# RetailCRM обновить значение поля клиента "Email-подписка" по API

Tags: веб-программирование, интернет-магазин, crm, ecommerce

## Постановка задачи

RetailCRM, версия 7.4.84
Версия API: v5

У клиента есть поле "Email-подписка":

[image: Поле "Email-подписка" в RetailCRM]

Задача - обновлять значение данного поля, используя [RetailCRM API V5](https://docs.retailcrm.ru/Developers/API/APIVersions/APIv5).

## Решение задачи

Использую метод `/api/v5/customers/{externalId}/edit`.

Получилось обновлять значение поля "Email-подписка" в состояние "Отписан" путем передачи в данных клиента значения:

```
customer[emailMarketingUnsubscribedAt] = <текущая_дата>
```

[image: RetailCRM упоминание поля emailMarketingUnsubscribedAt в справочнике методов API]

## Проблемы

При этом не получается установить значение поля "Email-подписка" в состояние "Подписан".

Попытки:

1. Передача

   customer[emailMarketingUnsubscribedAt] = <пустая_строка>

приводит к возникновению ошибки на стороне API:

> Invalid datetime "", expected format Y-m-d H:i:s.

2. Передача

   customer[emailMarketingUnsubscribedAt] = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

приводит к возникновению ошибки на стороне API:

> Invalid datetime "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

3. Передача

   customer[emailMarketingUnsubscribedAt] = null

не оказывает влияние на значение поля, и не приводит к возникновению ошибок.

Также я пробовал передавать в данных клиента

```
customer[emailMarketingUnsubscribed] = '0'
```

т.е. имя селекта на форме в RetailCRM + желаемое значение ('0' - Подписан).

## Вопрос

Как обновить поле клиента "Email-подписка" в состояние "Подписан", используя RetailCRM API v5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Процитирую ответ службы поддержки RetailCRM:

> Передать факт подписки, то что клиент подписан на рассылки можно так:
> в поле customer[subscribed] передать значение true
>
> А если хотите отписать, можете передать в этом поле false, либо же
> передать явную дату/время в поле
> customer[emailMarketingUnsubscribedAt]